# Show that if $f_{M}: L_{M} \to G_{M}$ is surjective for every maximal ideal $ M$ of $R$ then $f$ is surjective.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $f:L\to G$ be a homomorphism of modules over commutative ring $R$. Show that if $f_{M}: L_{M} \to G_{M}$ is surjective for every maximal ideal $ M$ of $R$ then $f$ is surjective.

Comment: This is Proposition 3.9 of Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: It is just injective. I try to do in surjective case. But I got stuck.

Comment: Localization is exact, hence - by looking at the cokernel - you are reduced to show that a module is zero if and only if all localizations are zero. If this is not well known to you, figure out a proof yourself or use search.

Comment: With your hints I got it :D. Thank you so much :).